# Sqlite convert cursor object to actual number

Tags: python, sqlite

I run the following code with an `issues` database with `sqlite3`:

```py
b = c.execute('SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ISSUES')
print(b)
```

The result is

```sql
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x126cff9d0>
```

How can I convert this object to an actual number

Comment: Have you read the Python docs about sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
b = c.execute('SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ISSUES')
for row in b:
    print(row)
```